# Simple authentication and encryption methods over TCP for microcontroller embedded device

Tags: security, authentication, tcp, embedded

I have designed a simple communications protocol, over raw TCP sockets, to enable simple messaging between some embedded devices. To put things in context, my embedded device is a box of electronics containing a relatively small microcontroller that is running a basic embedded RTOS (which essentially provides just task priority and message queueing) and TCP/IP stack. The intended use for the TCP protocol is to

1. Enable two or more 'boxes' to communicate with each other over a LAN in one building
2. To allow a box to exchange data with an external server over the Internet.

I now have a messaging protocol working between my metal boxes that I'm happy with. The basic messaging procedure between two boxes is basically:

1. Box 'A' initiates a socket connection to 'B'.
2. Box 'A' sends a message report or command sequence.
3. Box 'B' responds with an acknowledge and / or command response.
4. Box 'A' closes the socket.

What I would now like to do is to incorporate some level of security and authentication. The great restriction here is that I don't have any kind of OS or glorified TCP stack that can provide me with any security features; I just have simple TCP stack, and therefore I must implement security measures at application level, and with microcontroller limitations in mind.

The objectives I would like to meet are:

1. Authentication between devices. To achieve this, I'm intending to do the following measures:

   - Hold a table of known IPs from which connections shall only be accepted.
   - Each time a socket connection is established, unique identifiers are always exchanged first. The number might be a unique serial number for a given device, and must be known to the other devices.
2. Encryption of data, in the event that packets are somehow intercepted. Presumably I need some kind of cipher algorithm that isn't too 'expensive' to perform on a small microcontroller, used in conjuction with a unique key that is programmed into all devices. One such algorithm I've seen, which looks compact enough to implement in my code, is TEA (Tiny Encryption Algorithm).

I would be most grateful for any advice or pointers.

Comment: I would strongly suggest using SSL - perhaps you can find a lightweight implementation. Even if you're adamant that you must implement it by hand, you will almost surely end up with something that is functionally equivalent to SSL but of lower quality and cryptographic correctness.

Comment: Are you worried about man in the middle attacks?

Comment: I think you should read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Authentication_Protocol then do what it says. It seems to apply exactly to your situation. Doing crypto by hand is hard, it's better to copy someone else's work.

Comment: Kerrek SB: Thank you for your comment. Sadly at this stage it's not feasible to change the stack, but I'd definitely agree with you that it'd be the more ideal way, and in future I think that's the way it's going to go. However at this stage I am forced to try to implement some security measures myself. I guess it'll be a good learning exercise, if anything. Ariel: I think I would be, yes. Protecting against someone impersonating a remote 'box' is something I would like to achieve. Edit: Thank you for the Wikipedia link; I shall be reading through that over lunch!

Comment: In particular EAP-PSK and EAP-EKE seem to match what you need. Both require a pre-shared password.

Comment: if encryption is too expensive, you could try a custom or non-standard crc type checksum,  change up the location of the xor gates from the standard crcs.  (add the checksum to the sending packet and the receiver checks it).  The crypto algorithms are pretty easy to implement, if you have enough of a microcontroller to support an rtos and tcp/ip stack you probably have enough horsepower to implement them.  aes and/or des has reference code, libtomcrypt is good as well, once you see the implementations you can craft one by hand if needed.

Comment: Regarding TEA, you should use its more robust successor XXTEA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tea looks to be quite simple and will probably do what you need.

compiling for thumb with -O2 or similar optimizations:

arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc (Sourcery G++ Lite 2011.03-41) 4.5.2
encrypt 136 bytes decrypt 128 bytes

llvm 29
encrypt 92 bytes decrypt 96 bytes

compiling for generic arm...

gnu  encrypt 188 bytes, decrypt 184 bytes
llvm encrypt 112 bytes, decrypt 116 bytes

For authentication, is there a one to one relationship between the ip address table and the number of devices?  Basically does there need to be more than one unique identifier per device?  Are you wanting the other side that is making the connection to the embedded system to log in in some form or fashion? Or are you controlling the binaries/code on both ends and there are no users or no selection of devices (the programs know what to do), etc?  If each device has a known ip address, that ip address could be the key to the encryption (plus other bytes common to all or derived in some fashion that everyone knows) If a connection coming in is 1) not from the approved list 2) encryption fails when the embedded systems ip address based key fails then reject the connection.

Your security can only go so far anyway, if you need something really robust you probably need more horsepower in the embedded system and then implement one of the common/standard systems like ssl.

Answer (score 3):

Check [MatrixSSL](http://www.matrixssl.org/) - they boast a tiny size and embeddable capabilities. This is much better than re-inventing SSL/TLS yourself (which you would end up doing).